# How do I add a new SQL table to my Excel workbook using PowerPivot

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I have pivot table dashboards connected to SQL Server tables via PowerPivot. When the SQL tables have new data added all I have to do is refresh the Excel workbook to see these changes. But every time I add a new column or table in SQL I have to rebuild all these dashboards from scratch by establishing a new connection to the database. How can I simply refresh Excel to see changes I made on the SQL end?

Comment: You'll have to select the new column(s) in the design of that table. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413480(v=sql.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you'll have to select the new column(s) in the design of that table.
It comes down to this ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413480(v=sql.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)):

1. In the PowerPivot window, click the Design tab, and in the Properties group, click Table Properties.
   The name of the current workbook table is displayed in the Table Name box. The Source Name box contains the name of the table in the external data source. If columns are named differently in the source and in the workbook, you can toggle between the two sets of column names by selecting the options Source or PowerPivot data (workbook).
2. To change the table that is used as a data source, for Source Name, select a different table than the current one.
3. Change column mappings if needed:

   - To add columns that are present in the source but not in the workbook, select the checkbox beside the column name.
   - The actual data will be loaded into the workbook the next time you refresh.
   - If some columns in the workbook are no longer available in the current data source, a message appears in the notification area that lists the invalid columns. You do not need to do anything else.

Comment: This answers my question about adding a column to an existing field. But how do I add an entirely new table?? The table properties only lets me edit an existing table

Comment: That's correct. And by opening the `Existing Connections` and then opening the connection to SQL Server you can add tables/views.

Comment: Okay so I was able to add a new SQL table via existing connections and I build a new pivot dashboard from it. But when I refresh the workbook the SQL table disappears and the pivot dashboard turns blank.

Comment: Did you keep the workbook open the whole time during building the dashboard and refreshing? You never closed it without saving e.g.? It can't disappear just like that..

Comment: I originally added the new table under existing connections. I built the pivot dashboard and am able to manipulate the filters with no issues. I saved and closed.  When I open the document my new dashboard is there along with the table, but when I refresh all from the data tab my table disappears from the field list and the dashboard is blank.

Comment: That's weird. Are you able to share the workbook? Otherwise I'd report this to MS themselves.

Comment: It has PHI I cannot share it. I'll just have to recreate it from scratch.